# How to add authorization (Authorize button) in swagger for ocelot

Tags: .net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, ocelot

How can I add Authorize button in swagger, when I have ocelot api gateway?

[image]

I configure my service collection like that:

```
s.AddSwaggerForOcelot(configuration);

s.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ApiGateway" });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "Please enter into field the word 'Bearer' following by space and JWT",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    });
    c.ExampleFilters();
});
```

but it doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this configuration in all the downstream APIs of your Ocelot API Gateway.

Thus, the `securitySchemes` and `security` JSON objects will be included to each downstream API Open API Specification.